# How to automatically update "order" field of an item using VueDraggable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, vuedraggable

How to update order here after drag and drop?
Currently using Vue3 and
vue draggable( https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next).

```
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Test - 1",
      "order": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Test - 2",
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Test - 3",
      "order": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

If I now move Test - 2 to the top, the result should be:

```
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Test - 2",
      "order": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Test - 1",
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Test - 3",
      "order": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you just need to loop through the items each time the items order changes

**full working example:**

```js
<template>
    <draggable :list="items" 
               item-key="name"
               @change="onChange">
        <template #item="{ element }">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                {{ element.name }}
            </div>
        </template>
    </draggable>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

export default {
    components: {
        draggable,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'Test - 1',
                    order: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Test - 2',
                    order: 1,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Test - 3',
                    order: 2,
                },
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.reorder()
        },
        reorder() {
            this.items.forEach((item, index) => (item.order = index))
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

[image]